# removing x axis in error.bars

Tags: r, axis

I've been having a problem today, I want to remove the x-axis from the following R-plot, but it just won't disappear. I want the axis to be on top.
Is anybody able to help me?

```
library(psych)
temp <- describe(attitude)
error.bars(stats=temp,xaxt="n")
axis(3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fixInNamespace()` to edit the `error.bars()` function *in* the `psych` NAMESPACE. Try:

```
fixInNamespace(error.bars)
```

That will open the function in a rudimentary text editing window. Find the `axis()` calls and comment out the ones you don't want. Exit the editor and R will update the function in the NAMESPACE.

Then try using the function again.

Alternatively, you can print the code for `error.bars()` to the prompt, copy it into a text editor, change the name of the function, say to `my.error.bars`, and comment out the `axis()` calls as before. Save the function in a file and `source()` it into your session or copy and paste the function in. Then use to your heart's desire.

A third alternative, is to work out how `error.bars()` does it's base plotting - look at the code. Recreate that plot yourself, without axes, then call `error.bars()` with `add = TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you for the description. This means I'll just have to find another way to use error-bars, because otherwise I can't do my plot I need to fix.

Answer (score 2):

As in the comment, you can edit the source code. Easiest way is probably to use 'fix':

```
eb = fix(error.bars)
```

should pop up an editor. Change the axis(1,.etc.) calls to axis(3,.etc.). Then you have a new function called eb() that works like error.bars.

You might want to tweak some other things too, like the title which stomps on the axes when placed at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show what Gavin means with add=T :

```
group <- factor(rep(1:10,10))
y <- (1:10)[group] + rnorm(100)

grmean <- tapply(y,group,mean)
plot(1:10,grmean,xaxt="n",type="n")

unstacked <- unstack(data.frame(y,group),y~group)
error.bars(unstacked,add=T)
axis(3)
```

gives :
[image]