# Error Bar in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am in need for a good errorbar function.

I have already tried the package(psych) but in here I can't remove the x axis and I also tried the package(ggplot2) but in here I can't use a second y-axis. Can anybody recommend me a good package for making errorbars in R?

Comment: I think you dismissed the advice in the other question a bit prematurely. Editing the `error.bars()` function itself to suit your needs is not that difficult. I took @Spacedman's advice and looked at the function, you simply need to change two lines of code, on lines 72 and 81, by simply changing axis 1 to axis 3.

Comment: @Chase : the question was a good errorbar function. errbar is a good errorbar function.

Comment: @Sir Ksilem aka Kris Melis : please don't make two accounts. The acronym is funny, but if you get found out by the mods, both accounts will get suspended. You best contact team@stackoverflow.com asap with an explanation why you have two accounts and ask to merge these accounts.

Comment: kris melis was not a registered account, I now made it with my google account, which is sir ksilem. kris melis was free, I'm sorry for the troubles.

Comment: @Sir Ksilem : I thought something like that. Still, mail to team@stackoverflow to tell them, and they'll be happy to merge both accounts for you. Welcome to SO

Comment: @Joris Meys: Ok, I did that, thx for the advice. And I like this place, my questions get answered pretty quick. I hope I can also help other people in the future.

Comment: @Joris - fair and valid point. I had taken the comment in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754356/removing-x-axis-in-error-bars) to indicate that wasn't really a viable option, but after looking at the code in the function, it is all pretty visible and easy to see where the plotting code is set up.

Comment: @Chase : Gavin gave even a better solution : use add=T. I didn't check the help files well enough, I just went to the source :)

Comment: but, if i use gavin's solution, I can't distribute my scripts?

Comment: @JorisMeys If i change the original package and then send the script to somebody else. So they install the package psych, they don't have my changes to the script. So if I put my script on the internet, nobody can use it...

Comment: @JorisMeys I can't, i don't have 20 reputation point yet. But that's the point, you can't delete your x-axis in the package psych, or am i completely looking at something wrong? that's why I'm now using the hMisc package. If I'm wrong, please tell me, I just recently started using R for a project in school.

Comment: @SirKsilem : True. They didn't merge your accounts yet? Well, the solution I gave on the other question, is exactly what Gavin meant. It depends whether you want to calculate your error bars yourself, or unstack your dataframe so it happens for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see eg `?errbar` in the package `Hmisc`

```
 group <- factor(sample(1:10,100,T))
y <- (1:10)[group] + rnorm(100)
grmean <- tapply(y,group,mean)
lims <- tapply(y,list(group),FUN = sd)*2
errbar( 1:10, grmean, grmean + lims, grmean - lims , xaxt="n" )
axis(3)
```

gives : 
[image]